# How to get discrete data out of 2D Mathematica Interpolating Function?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am using NDSolve[] to integrate an orbital trajectory (with ExplicitRungeKutta). Mathematica gives me

```
{{x[t]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,2000.}},<>][t],
y[t]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,2000.}},<>][t]}}
```

My question is how do I get this into table of raw data where t=0,1,2...2000?
I tried:

```
path = Table[Solved, {t, 0, tmax}];
```

But I get a huge table of stuff like this:

```
{{{x[0] -> -0.523998, y[0] -> 0.866025}}, {{x[1] -> -0.522714, 
y[1] -> 0.886848}}, {{x[2] -> -0.480023, 
y[2] -> 0.951249}}, {{x[3] -> -0.369611, y[3] -> 1.02642}}
```

I want something like:

```
{{{-0.523998, 0.866025}}, {{-0.522714, 0.886848}}, etc
```

I don't have a lot of experience working with these Interpolating functions, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I managed to solve this problem.
To anyone who is wondering about how I solved this.

I did the following:

    coordx[t_] = x[t] /. Solved;
    coordy[t_] = y[t] /. Solved;
    path = Table[{t, coordx[t], coordy[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}];

Now my path table is formatted properly, and I can do

    path[[2]]

and it responds

    {1, {-0.522714}, {0.886848}}

Answer (score 3):

You are getting back **rules**, not functions directly.  In order to access the interpolating functions themselves, you need to do a rule replacement.

Instead of

```
Table[Solved, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

you need

```
Table[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. Solved], {t, 0, tmax}];
```

`Solved` (which I assume is the output of `NDSolve`) is just a list of rules which will allow for the expressions `x[t]` and `y[t]` to be replaced by the corresponding interpolating functions, which you then evaluate.

Check out the F1 help for `NDSolve` for more examples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this looks cleaner than what I did!

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the [PropertyValue[]](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PropertyValue.html) function if you are interested in the points that were used to interpolate - which sometimes is interesing when using NDSolve[]. See the example below:

```
x = Range[1, 10];
y = x^2;
pts = Transpose[{x, y}];
f = Interpolation[pts];
Plot[f[t], {t, 1, 10}]
(*getting the coordinates*)
X = PropertyValue[f, "Coordinates"][[1]]
Y = PropertyValue[f, "ValuesOnGrid"]
ListPlot[Transpose[{X, Y}]]
```

In such way you can extract almost any properties of any object. To get the list of properties use [PropertyList[]](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PropertyList.html) function. In the above example it returns:

```
PropertyList[f]
{"Coordinates", "DerivativeOrder", "Domain", "ElementMesh", 
"Evaluate", "GetPolynomial", "Grid", "InterpolationMethod", 
"InterpolationOrder", "MethodInformation", "Methods", 
"OutputDimensions", "Periodicity", "PlottableQ", "Properties", 
"QuantityUnits", "Unpack", "ValuesOnGrid"}
```